# Do I need a new door? Screen door? Just frame?

Tags: door-frame, dry-rot

Do I need new door frame too? (Wood rot)

Any help appreciated !!
We are hoping to move in next year or so and this house has given us so many issues. Now we found what I guessed to be dry rot under the carpet by our back exterior door. The opposite end of the door has been a bit off the hinges which may have contributed but there was some caulking missing exteriorly that I temporarily caulked.

Our budget is pretty small for repairs I’m wondering if anyone can give us an idea of the extent of damage or estimated cost and repairs needed here. I’m in Ohio if that helps any.[image: pics of rotten subfloor, the cracked opposite side of door, and looking up from basement]

Comment: you have multiple questions here. It will be closed if left that way, so edit to ask one question. You can ask another question in another post.  It is strictly forbidden to discuss prices or cost , as they vary so much from region to region.  The good news is the door frame loot split from someone forcing the screen door open too far.  All look to be minor fixes.

Comment: The top right picture looks like the _floor_ has rotted out. That's not going to be fixed by replacing the door. That will prevent further damage, but you'll seriously want to fix that before installing the new door. _Can_ it be a DIY job? Can _you_ DIY it? Sure! If you have tools & skills and/or are willing to buy/learn.